# iPhone stay connected to WiFi even if there is not internet

Tags: iphone, network, wifi

We are developing an app to configure a WiFi enabled device. App connects to device over WiFi and allows config + shows some stats on the app. We want to ensure that when app on iPhone request to connect to device over Wifi the iPhone doesn't switch to mobile data network.

Is the a way to prevent iPhone to switch to mobile when connect to WiFi with no internet?

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: You have to disable data usage for your App. There should be a way to do it, however, I have never tried to do this. But the developer documentation :)

Comment: Yeah. but can an app do that??

Comment: As I state you should be able to disable data usage by default for your app. I just don't know how to do it :)